# How to create a generic class with generic using a known type as parameter?

Tags: c#

Let's say that I have a non-generic class `NonGenericClass` and I'd like to have a generic class `GenericClass<T>` whose method would return `T<NonGenericClass>`.

Pseduo code example:

```
public class NonGeneric Class {}

public class GenericClass<T>  
{
    public T<NonGenericClass> foo()
    {
        return new T<NonGenericClass>();
    } 
}
```

How would I accomplish this in c#?

Comment: `T<NonGenericClass>` doesn't make any sense. Either you don't know, so you use `T`, or you do know, and use `NonGenericClass`

Comment: There's no way through the constraint system to express "this type parameter must be an open generic type with arity 1" which is what your code assumes about the type parameter.

Comment: You have a generic class which has `NonGenericClass` as generic type?

Comment: You'd have to add a constrain on `T` that it is a generic interface or class that takes `NonGenericClass` as the type, but you wouldn't do `T<NonGenericClass>`.  For example you could have `where T : IEnumberable<NonGenericClass>` but you'd still just use `T` as the return type.  What actual problem are you trying to solve as this looks like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: I call this - in no derogatory way - the [Generic Rabbit Hole of Madness](http://scotthannen.org/blog/2018/04/05/the-generic-rabbit-hole-of-madness.html). I think we've all done it. If we're trying to figure out this problem then it's unlikely we've written any code that uses what we're trying to figure out how to make. It's much better to just write the code we need without generics and then see if it reveals something that we can simplify with generics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class NonGenericClass {}

public class OtherGenericClass<T>{}

public class GenericClass<T,T2>
    where T: OtherGenericClass<T2>, new()
    where T2: NonGenericClass
{
    public T Foo()
    {
        return new T();
    }
}
```

All of these constraints actually mean something, so this would make sense if you actually needed all of those constraints. It just makes my mind dizzy trying to imagine them. Even if these were real classes with real names and all of this served a purpose, I'd have a hard time understanding it shortly after I wrote it and the next developer would hate me.

What this means is that `Foo()` will always return `OtherGenericClass<T2>` and `T2` will always be `NonGenericClass`.

If you attempt to do anything with classes that inherit from any of these types you'll get all sorts of compiler errors about covariance that will make your head explode. That is the process I have documented [here](http://scotthannen.org/blog/2018/04/05/the-generic-rabbit-hole-of-madness.html). The harder you try to make it work the worse it will get.

I suspect that this happens because we try to create these generic classes before we write the code that *needs* those generic classes. Otherwise we would just write the classes we need right now and *maybe* refactor a little bit to use generics if we find out that they make sense.

What happens is that we get our generics to compile, then start writing the code that depends on those classes, and that's when we realize that what we've built isn't exactly what we need. Or the complexity infects the code that depends on those classes and now they need all sorts of generic constraints too. Eventually we hit a wall where we either can't get it to compile, can't remember what we were trying to accomplish, or both.

The `new()` constraint is just because the method returns `new T()`. It won't compile unless without that constraint, which specifies that `T()` must be something that has a constructor with no arguments.